# Which Machine Learning algorithm should I use to detect abnormal behaviour in a home-automation environment

Tags: algorithms, machine-learning

I want a system to learn what is "normal" in a home-automation(KNX) environment.

I have data like, address/group address, timestamp,... is there a matching machine learning algorithm I could use in that situation?

I started to read a book abt Machine learning, but I'm not quite sure which kind of algorithm I need

If machine learning is the right thing for me here to use, which language should I use? I have most experience in Java, but also little in R and Python(but nothing machine learning related yet)

Comment: What kind of "behaviour" do you want to detect?  What would you classify as an anomaly?

Comment: e.g a light switch is pressed at a unusual time, or the value of a thermostat is out of a specific range(The value of the thermostat was always between 19 and 22°, now there is a telegram with the value 15, that would be an anomaly). So there may be abnormal value and/or abnormal time of a telegram

Comment: Just read up on anomaly detection/outlier detection and pick a simple algorithm at first, perhaps $k$-nearest neighbors with a manually defined distance metrics.  That is a simple algorithm, and should be able to flag the simplest-to-detect outliers.